# Set the background color of DataGridHeaderBackground in Silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a application where user can set the datagrid header background color in runtime. How can I do this? I tried the same through the following code but it is throwing exception.I have used binding and but it's not working.

```
var style = this.Resources["DataGridHeaderStyle"] as Style;
style.Setters.SetValue(DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty, "Red");
```

Comment: "Throwing expection"??  It might be helpful if you included exactly what the exception says?

Answer (score 0):

Without further details (such as the exception you are getting) its difficult to see why you are getting an exception.  I suspect that the `style` variable has a null reference.

I also suspect that the reason its null is that the "DataGridHeaderStyle" doesn't exist in the resource dictionary of the `this` object, which I would guess is a `UserControl`.  In order to acquire the `Style` you need to do this look up on the actual `FrameworkElement` object that holds the `Style` in its `Resources` property.  (Note programmatic access to the resources does not cascade up the visual tree searching the resource of parents).

However, assuming you can fix that you still have a problem.  The use of `SetValue` on the `Setters` colleciton itself is nothing like what you actually need to be doing.

You need to be doing this:-

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty,  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
```

Of course this only works if the style doesn't already contain an `Setter` for the property.  Hence a more robust version is:-

```
var setter = style.Setters
                  .OfType<Setter>()
                  .Where(s => s.Property == DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

if (setter != null)
    setter.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
else
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty,  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
```